# How can I properly use CMake and SWIG to generate a .dll that can be used on go?

Tags: cmake, dll, swig, cgo

I am trying to create a .dll to use it in go, I am using CMake and Visual Studio. My plan was create and test the library in c++, then use SWIG and CMake to generate the go module and handle the dependencies.

When I modified the CMakelist.txt file to add the SWIG part, the 3rd party libraries I installed were no longer being read on in my code.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling them, but the won't reinstall. I keep getting this error:

```
CMake Error at scripts/cmake/vcpkg_execute_build_process.cmake:134 (message):
    Command failed: "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/bin/cmake.exe" --build . --config Release --target install -- -v -j9
    Working Directory: C:/Users/v-omarkhalil/Desktop/Work/VCPKG/vcpkg/buildtrees/arrow/x64-windows-rel
    See logs for more information:
      C:\Users\v-omarkhalil\Desktop\Work\VCPKG\vcpkg\buildtrees\arrow\install-x64-windows-rel-out.log

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  installed/x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_build.cmake:74 (vcpkg_execute_build_process)
  installed/x64-windows/share/vcpkg-cmake/vcpkg_cmake_install.cmake:16 (vcpkg_cmake_build)
  ports/arrow/portfile.cmake:66 (vcpkg_cmake_install)
  scripts/ports.cmake:147 (include)


error: building arrow:x64-windows failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Elapsed time to handle arrow:x64-windows: 11 min
Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
Then check for known issues at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+in%3Atitle+arrow
You can submit a new issue at:
    https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/new?title=[arrow]+Build+error&body=Copy+issue+body+from+C%3A%2FUsers%2Fv-omarkhalil%2FDesktop%2FWork%2FVCPKG%2Fvcpkg%2Finstalled%2Fvcpkg%2Fissue_body.md
```

I have no idea what could be causing this or how to fix it. any ideas?

here is my CMakelists.txt:

```
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for BlobConnectionTestCmake, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

# Enable Hot Reload for MSVC compilers if supported.
if (POLICY CMP0141)
  cmake_policy(SET CMP0141 NEW)
  set(CMAKE_MSVC_DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT "$<IF:$<AND:$<C_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>,$<CXX_COMPILER_ID:MSVC>>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:EditAndContinue>,$<$<CONFIG:Debug,RelWithDebInfo>:ProgramDatabase>>")
endif()
 
project ("BlobConnectionTestCmake")
set(GO_MODULE_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/go-modules")
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY GO_MODULE_DIRECTORY ${GO_MODULE_DIRECTORY})
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${GO_MODULE_DIRECTORY})
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_library(Azure_connector SHARED "BlobConnectionTestCmake.cpp" "BlobConnectionTestCmake.h" "ConnectionHeader.hpp")

# Add source to this proje ct's executable.
add_executable (BlobConnectionTestCmake2 "BlobConnectionTestCmake.cpp" "BlobConnectionTestCmake.h" "ConnectionHeader.hpp")

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12)
  set_property(TARGET BlobConnectionTestCmake2 PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()

# TODO: Add tests and install targets if needed.
    find_package(Arrow CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(BlobConnectionTestCmake2 PRIVATE "$<IF:$<BOOL:${ARROW_BUILD_STATIC}>,Arrow::arrow_static,Arrow::arrow_shared>")

    find_package(Parquet CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(BlobConnectionTestCmake2 PRIVATE "$<IF:$<BOOL:${ARROW_BUILD_STATIC}>,Parquet::parquet_static,Parquet::parquet_shared>")

  find_package(azure-storage-blobs-cpp REQUIRED)
  target_link_libraries(BlobConnectionTestCmake2 PRIVATE Azure::azure-storage-blobs)

find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

swig_add_library(Azure_connector_swig TYPE SHARED LANGUAGE go SOURCES Azure_exp_connector.i)
swig_link_libraries(Azure_connector_swig Azure_connector)

find_package(Arrow REQUIRED)
swig_link_libraries(Azure_connector_swig "$<IF:$<BOOL:${ARROW_BUILD_STATIC}>,Arrow::arrow_static,Arrow::arrow_shared>")

find_package(Parquet REQUIRED)
swig_link_libraries(Azure_connector_swig "$<IF:$<BOOL:${ARROW_BUILD_STATIC}>,Parquet::parquet_static,Parquet::parquet_shared>")

find_package(azure-storage-blobs-cpp REQUIRED)
swig_link_libraries(Azure_connector_swig  Azure::azure-storage-blobs)
```

Comment: "I have no idea what could be causing this or how to fix it. any ideas?" - The idea is to read log file, referred in the error message: `C:\Users\v-omarkhalil\Desktop\Work\VCPKG\vcpkg\buildtrees\arrow\install-x64-windows-rel-out.log`

Comment: if I understood anything from it, I would not be here

Comment: That log file contains the error message about building your project. Without it even experts cannot solve your problem. You need to include that file (at least, the **first error message** contained in it) into the question post.